# Chrome Extension crashes with "bad extension message webRequestInternal.eventHandled"

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that out of nowhere crashes, so I saw that you could debug your chrome by activating the logging, so that's what I did, and I noticed that before the crash happens, it's thrown an error of: " bad extension message webRequestInternal.eventHandled : terminating renderer.", so maybe this error occur in one of  webRequests listeners. But I don't know what to do anymore to make it right.

This is the log error that happens before the function closes:

```
[1888:3844:17965500:ERROR:extension_function.cc(143)] bad extension message webRequestInternal.eventHandled : terminating renderer.
[1888:3844:17965625:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(181)] WR percent 2643: http://mypage.com/test: = 0.985185
[1888:3844:17965625:VERBOSE1:web_request_time_tracker.cc(181)] WR percent 2644: http://mypage.com/test: 123/123 = 1
[1888:3464:17965734:VERBOSE1:speech_input_extension_manager.cc(228)] Extension unloaded. Requesting to enforce stop...
```

I have 2 webRequest listeners:

The OnBeforeRequest Page blocking:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(blockURLs,
    {urls: ["http://*\/*", "https://*\/*"]}, //I have to use all because I use specific page filters
    ["blocking"]
);

function blockURLs(details){    

    var url = details.url.split('/');
    if(STRING_OF_SERVERS.indexOf(url[2]) < 0 || details.url.indexOf('.css') > -1 )
    return {cancel: true}; 
}
```

And the onBeforeSendHeaders (This is probably the one erroneous):

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
      function(details) {
                    var cookie_found = false;
                    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {



                      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'Cookie') {

                            //details.requestHeaders.splice(i,1); //,localStorage['COOKIES']
                            //alert("ADDED: " + localStorage['COOKIES']);

                            if(window['SERVIDOR_TEMP_DATA_' + SERVER_INDEX]['COOKIES'] != ''){
                                details.requestHeaders[i] = new Object();
                                details.requestHeaders[i].name = 'Cookie';
                                details.requestHeaders[i].value = window['SERVIDOR_TEMP_DATA_' + SERVER_INDEX]['COOKIES'];
                            }else{
                                window['SERVIDOR_TEMP_DATA_' + SERVER_INDEX]['COOKIES'] = details.requestHeaders[i].value;


                        cookie_found = true;
                        break;
                      }
                    }

                    if(cookie_found == false && window['SERVIDOR_TEMP_DATA_' + SERVER_INDEX]['COOKIES'] != ''){
                            var i = details.requestHeaders.length;
                            details.requestHeaders[i] = new Object();
                            details.requestHeaders[i].name = 'Cookie';
                            details.requestHeaders[i].value = window['SERVIDOR_TEMP_DATA_' + SERVER_INDEX]['COOKIES'];
                    }


    //console.log(details.url);
    //console.log(details.requestHeaders);

    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },


  {urls: URLS_TYPE, types : ["main_frame", "sub_frame", "xmlhttprequest", "object",  "stylesheet", "script", "image",  "other"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);



  //StartClicking();
});
```

The variables not specified:

```
*var URLS_TYPE is an array of Sites allowed
*var STRING_OF_SERVERS is a String containing all the possible combination of sites that are allowed
```

And in my application I make a lot of web requests, and I don't know what to do anymore :/
What could possibly be throwing this crash?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Reduce your extension to a minimal extension which reproduces the problem, and create a bug report at http://new.crbug.com/

Comment: what do you mean reduce extension to a minimal extension?

Comment: Remove the code which do not contribute to crashing.

Comment: That's the problem, I don't know where the crash is taking place, if it's in my code or in fact on the webRequest thing, because it works for hours this way, but out of nowhere it crashes :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to find the answer.
the problem is that if the Request Headers come missing any information required , it just crashes instead of reporting an error.

My details.requestHeader was returning a cookie that only has a name and no value attribute, so If I added the value attribute the crash would go away.

Cookie object is supposed to come like this:

```
{ name: "key", value: "val"}
```

and I was generating only `{name: "key"}` since I was adding an undefined value, After I used `JSON.Stringify(details.requestHeaders)` I could see that it was missing and now problem solved.

I just had to make sure the cookie value wasn't undefined, if it was just add a empty string or whatever you want.